# Getting GotoMeeting access token using PHP CURL

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

I am creating a Wordpress Plugin that would create a meeting after some transaction but I don't know how to get the token. I made some tests but doesn't seem to work.

Tried doing some post CURL.

```
$consumerKey = "consumer_key_here";
$url = "https://api.getgo.com/oauth/v2/authorize?client_id={$consumerKey}&response_type=code"; 

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/32.0.1700.107 Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
$test = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
}
print $test;
```

This should be redirected to the desired redirect url with a response code along the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

To encode these values, open an [encoding site](http://base64encode.org) and paste in the consumerKey, add a colon (:), and then paste in the consumerSecret. No spaces, no quotes, no brackets. Submit the values and an encoded value is returned that will look something like: `ZXhhbXBsZV9jbGllbnRfaWQ6ZXhhbXBsZV9jbGllbnRfc2VjcmV0==`.

```
$ch = curl_init();
if($ch) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $token="for this you need to use documentation ";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Authorization: Basic '.$token,'Accept:application/json'));

    $curlulr="https://api.getgo.com/oauth/v2/token";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $curlulr);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

    $data = 'grant_type=authorization_code'.
    '&code={responseKey}';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    $rmv_results = curl_exec($ch);
    if($rmv_results === false) {
        echo('Error performing rmv lookup: '.curl_errno($ch).' - '.curl_error($ch).' (Message ID: '.basename(__FILE__).'-'.__LINE__.')');
    } // end if errors
    // echo "3";
    curl_close($ch);

    print_r($rmv_results);
    echo ">><br>". $rmv_results;
}
```

Comment: To encode these values, open an encoding site (https://www.base64encode.org (link is external)) and paste in the consumerKey, add a colon (:), and then paste in the consumerSecret. No spaces, no quotes, no brackets. Submit the values and an encoded value is returned that will look something like: ZXhhbXBsZV9jbGllbnRfaWQ6ZXhhbXBsZV9jbGllbnRfc2VjcmV0==.

Comment: include relevant information in your answer and not as comment. (prevents downvoting).